# Bot Framework - Facebook Prompt issue

Tags: facebook, bots, botframework

I am using bot framework. I have my Facebook bot online and I am inspecting all the requests in my server. Sometimes my server is not receiving prompts answers (HeroCards buttons work perfect). If I retry and send a message many times, it works. If I use the emulator it works fine.

[image]
I wrote three times "pollo" to get the answer.

```
module.exports = (bot, builder, connector) => {

bot.dialog('/delivery', [
    (session) => {
        session.send('Bienvenido a 99UNO Delivery.');

        let msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
            .attachments([
                new builder.HeroCard(session)
                    .title('Pizza')
                    .subtitle('Todas nuestras pizzas.')
                    .images([
                        builder.CardImage.create(session, 'http://www.cateringolivia.com.ar/fotos/ser2_1g.jpg')
                            .tap(builder.CardAction.showImage(session, 'http://mx.cdn01.mundotkm.com/2016/01/e9a9d35c744f3ff11a97e32274411d8b_large.jpeg')),
                    ])
                    .buttons([
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, 'Pizza', 'Seleccionar')
                    ]),
                new builder.HeroCard(session)
                    .title('Parrilla')
                    .subtitle('Carne, Pollo, Achuras.')
                    .images([
                        builder.CardImage.create(session, 'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/85/0c/c7/parrilla-tour-buenos.jpg')
                            .tap(builder.CardAction.showImage(session, 'https://restorando-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/s--L2hhcZz2--/c_fit,f_auto,h_500,w_700/v1416341745/restaurant_photos/x/6939/52684/restaurante_parrilla-atahualpa_centro_10390894_1485980544972645_3906330496111888189_n.jpg')),
                    ])
                    .buttons([
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, 'Parrilla', 'Seleccionar')
                    ])
            ]);
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, 'Pizza|Parrilla', {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.beginDialog('/' + results.response.entity.toLowerCase());
    }
]);

bot.dialog('/pizza', [
    (session) => {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Qué gusto desea pedir?', 'mozzarella|napolitana|jamon', {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.endDialog('Ya estamos llevando una pizza de ' + results.response.entity + ' a tu casa. Que lo disfrutes!');
    }
]);

bot.dialog('/parrilla', [
    (session) => {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Qué desea pedir?', 'vacio|pollo', {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.endDialog('Ya estamos llevando el ' + results.response.entity + ' a tu casa. Que lo disfrutes!');
    }
]);


};
```

Server: Nodejs in Amazon ec2. Using morgan in index.js:

```
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status - [:date[clf]] - :remote-addr - :response-time'));
```

Any idea?

Comment: Really hard to help without looking to the code and getting more information about where this is hosted/more details, etc.

Comment: I edit my question